# Determining a sample size

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I'm working through Probability and Statistics by DeGroot, and I'm on page 276; reading through the paragraph on 'Determining a Sample Size'.

I'm slightly confused here as I'm unsure of the two approaches taken, and why they differ and would really appreciate some clarification!

1. Suppose that a random sample of size n is to be taken from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance 9. We shall determine the minimum value of n for which:
   $$Pr(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|\le1)\ge0.95$$

The sample mean will have a normal distribution for which the mean is $\mu$ and the standard deviation $3/n^{1/2}$. Therefore if we let:
$$Z=\frac{n^{1/2}}{3}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)$$

Q. Why is the standard deviation given in that form? I understand that $Var(\bar{X}_n)=\sigma^2/n$, but to me it would make sense if it was given as $\left(\frac{3}{n^{1/2}}\right)^2$, and how did he get $n^{1/2}$ on the numerator?

Secondly, he gives another paragraph on the example: Heights of Men and Women.

Suppose that heights in inches for women has a mean $65$ and standard deviation 1 and for men a mean of $68$ and standard deviation of 2. Suppose also that one woman is selected at random and, independently, one man is selected at random. We shall determine the probability that the woman will be taller than the man.

Let W denote the height of the selected woman, and let M denote the height of the selected man. Then the difference $W-M$ has a normal distribution with mean $65-68$ and variance $1^2+2^2=5$, therefore:
$$Z=\frac{1}{5^{1/2}}(W-M+3)$$

Q. I cannot seem to understand why the form of the standard deviation is given so different here compared to the previous one.

Then he provides this:

$$Pr(W>M)=Pr(W-M>0)=Pr(Z>\frac{3}{5^{1/2}})$$

Q. Why did the form of Z change here relative to the previous one given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question: the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, and the formula for a $Z$ statistic uses the standard deviation, not the variance. Hence, you must have
$$Z
=\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n}}
=\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
=\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}.$$

Second Question: you're comparing means in this problem. This is a completely different test from comparing a single sample mean to a particular value. When you do that, your standard error is no longer $\sigma/\sqrt{n},$ but this:
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}},$$
and as the denominators are both $1,$ that's where the $\sqrt{5}$ comes from.

Third Question: There actually is no difference from the second form to the third form. The author is algebraically manipulating the expressions so as to be able to compare $Z$ to something. A few steps missing:
$$P(W-M>0)=P(W-M+3>3)=P\!\left(\frac{W-M+3}{\sqrt{5}}>\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\right)=P\!\left(Z>\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the standard deviation ($\sigma$) and the standard error $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$. If the variance of the total is $\sigma^2$, then the variance of mean values of samples drawn from this total is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. To get the standard deviation, you just draw the square root from this variance and get $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$.

In the first example, the variance is 9 and the number of cases is *n*. So, the standard error of means of samples drawn from this grand total is $\frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{n}}$, or $\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Since $Z=\frac{(\mu-\bar{x})}{\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}}$, you can rewrite it as $Z=\frac{(\mu-\bar{x})*\sqrt(n)}{3}$, which is the same as the given formula: $Z=\frac{\sqrt(n)}{3}*(\mu-\bar{x})$. (which should answer the first question)

In the second case, you draw only one case from the grand total. Since the size of the sample is exactly 1, $\sqrt{n}$ is also exactly 1. Z, therefore, is: $Z=\frac{(x_{men}-x_{women})}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{1}}}$. You can get the second problem from this formula.